# Has the Stack Exchange websites' design started to update faster than before?

Tags: support

I am not sure if it is just me, but I feel in the last six months the changes on the SE interface have been occurring at a rate much greater than when I began using this site.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: They doubled dev capacity. Lunch and coffee breaks are no longer allowed, no more vacation, no sick leave, working on Saturday and Sunday, no sleep. Glad you noticed those measures improved stuff ....

Comment: It's mainly small design changes, so yeah doesn't take long to do them. Bigger updates are listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-discovery), and taking long time.